# Retrieve matched text from input.text.matches and store into context variable in watson conversation

Tags: regex, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I am dealing with **IBM Watson Conversation**. I have a text that contains few **letters and digits** i.e. `age is 26`.

I have written a regex to match the digits from the text. It is done using `.*?[0-9]+.*?`. Now, I want those matched digits into **context variables**.

*How to place the matched digits into context variable ?*

When my condition matches with having `input.text.matches('.*?[0-9]+.*?')`, then I want to place only digits to my **context variable**.

**For Ex:**

```
{
    "context": {
               "digit": { input.text } 
    }
}
```

Here `input.text` takes the whole text and places it into **digit** variable.

**How to place only digits by applying regular expression on text ?**

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract regular expressions from input text as follows:

```
input.text.extract('.*?([0-9]+).*?', 1)
```

The first part is your regular expression. The second parameter is the group ID.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is required for the extraction to work, so if we want to extract the whole matched substring, we use 0 for the extract_id as follows:

```
input.text.extract('[0-9]+', 0)
```