# How to extract a numerical value from an input string using IBM Watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

When using the IBM Watson conversation builder,
how do I extract the (floating point) numerical value from a sentence?
For example, suppose the user typed:
  *Please make a payment of €1,051.84, thanks.*

How can I extract the currency amount?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39816501/1167890

Comment: Thanks Simon, that's helpful. 
The answer posted there is that it can't be done using the conversation tool, that is ( possibly / probably ) correct, but it is rather unsatisfying.
I wonder, could an "entity" be used and have the numerical value assigned to it?

Comment: Entities are explicit keywords at the moment. Development are investigating the issue you mention though.

Comment: OK, thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers can now be extracted via System Entities which are available in the tooling.

Comment: that's great. I'll give it a go.